# How split Double or Triple Spaces Sentences word by word into Array Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, text, fs

I am new to node js.I am Pretty Confused that how to split these sentence by removing authors name and get the quotes into a single array by words count.

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvations/Quotables/master/author-quote.txt

I would like to do this pattern

```
{
  quotes: 'hello world',
  wordCount: 2
}
```

My Try

```
const readline = require('linebyline'),
      rl = readline('./data.txt');

rl.on('line', function(line, lineCount, byteCount) {

    let lineSplit = line.split("  ");


    // I don't what to do

}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e,"ERROR")
});
```

Comment: `linebyline` an npm module right? Can you paste link to it

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline @akinjide

Comment: @Nane, as I am checking your author-quote.txt, is not consistent, it's not fixed author name would separate by tab or space, so split logic won't works instead take all auther in array and just compare line with array and remove matched auther name from a line, it will be more accurate.

Comment: Hmm I Think your comment will work Perfectly @AbhijitJagtap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved and a lil less code:

```js
var a = "A. A. Milne If you live to be a hundred, I want to live to be a hundred minus one day so I never have to live without you."

 a = a.substring(a.indexOf("\t") + 1); 

console.log(a.split(/[\s\t\n\r]+/));
```

> \s is the escape for **space**
>
> \t is the escape for **tab**
>
> \n is the escape for **line feed**
>
> \r is the escape for **carriage return**

```
 const readline = require('linebyline'),
       rl = readline('./data.txt');

  var finalResult = [];

  rl.on('line', function(line, lineCount, byteCount) {
       line = line.substring(line.indexOf("\t") + 1); 
       finalResult.push({
         quotes: line,
         wordcount:  line.split(/[\s\t\n\r]+/).length
       });
 }).on('error', function(e) {
 console.log(e,"ERROR")
 });
```

If the author is not tab separated by the quote you can't identification that.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alvations/Quotables/master/author-quote.txt",
    success: (response) => {
      var lines = response.split(/\n/),
        fn = function() {
          var line = lines.pop();
          if (!line) return;

          var t = line.indexOf("\t");

          if (t != -1) {
            line = line.substring(t + 1);
             console.log(lines.length, ' OK');
            //console.log(line, "(", line.split(/[\t\s\n\r]+/).length,")");
          } else {
            console.log(lines.length, ' NOT OK',  '***', line, '***');
          }
        };

      var id = setInterval(function() {
        if (lines.length) {
          fn();
        } else {
          clearInterval(id);
          console.log('DONE!');
        }
      }, 2);

    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As per OP's sample output, quote should not contain the name. Word count will also take a hit.

Comment: @blueren oh, I missed the " removing authors  " :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = "A. A. Milne    If you live to be a hundred, I want to live to be a hundred minus one day so I never have to live without you."

a = a.substring(a.indexOf("\t") + 1); 

//gives 

//"If you live to be a hundred, I want to live to be a hundred minus one day so I never have to live without you."


a.trim().split(/\s+/).length

// gives you the word count (29)
```

**So your code should be:**

```
const readline = require('linebyline'),
      rl = readline('./data.txt');

var finalResult = [];

rl.on('line', function(line, lineCount, byteCount) {
    line = line.substring(line.indexOf("\t") + 1);
   finalResult.push({
           quotes: line,
           wordcount:  line.trim().split(/\s+/).length
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log(e,"ERROR")
});
```

Comment: Would You Please Explain what is ```\t```

Comment: ```\t``` is a special character that denotes a tab space.

Comment: actually,  problem is I observed author-quote.txt, and some line author separated by space not tab so above logic will not work for that.

Comment: eg Abraham Lincoln Always bear in mind that your own resolution to succeed is more important than any other.

Comment: Dang. Yes. Looks like the text file is inconsistent with the tabs following the names. @Nane - Is the data.txt your final file or is it just an example file you're working on?

Comment: If the author is not tab separated by the rest you can't identify him except if you have a list of authors names and you can try to match the beginning of the string against that but it will be a pain.  There are over 30K quotes in there and most of them looks like are ok. Check the last portion of my response  :)

Comment: @blueren That's is My actual File

Answer (score 1):

I used the npm package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/line-by-line`, but you can use any other package

```
const readline = require('line-by-line')
const rl = new readline('author-quote.txt')

let data = []

rl.on('line', function (line) {
   let sentence = line.substring(line.indexOf("\t") + 1)

   data.push({
     count: sentence.split(' ').length,
     quote: sentence
   })
})

rl.on('end', function() {
   console.log(data) // or write to file
})
```

Comment: Would You Please Explain what is ```\t```

Comment: actually, problem is I observed author-quote.txt, and some line author separated by space not tab so above logic will not work for that.

Comment: `\t` is the escape for tab.  You can use a regex to search between `tab, spaces and carriage return` if any occurs